# Getting all paths in an array

Tags: algorithm

I have a list structured like follows:

```
s = [
  [
    [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  ],
  [  
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
    [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
  ],
  # And so on
]
```

For each element at the first index, `s[0]`, if the second sub-array, `s[0][i][1]`, matches a corresponding first element in `s[1]`, then we have a path, or a part of a path. It's complicated so I'll give an example:

```
s = [
  [
    [[0, 1, 1], *[0, 0, 0]*], <---- This goes to multiple possibilities
    [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  ],
  [  
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [*[0, 0, 0]*, [1, 0, 0]], <- here
    [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
    [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
    [*[0, 0, 0]*, [0, 1, 1]] <- and here
  ],
  # And so on
]
```

How can I find the amount of paths for each given element?

Comment: It's a Dynamic Programming + DFS/BFS graph traversal problem. I hope these keywords can help you find the answer by searching. 
You can use DFS/BFS to traverse from top-left to bottom-right element and use a 'cache' or map to record each position's number of paths. If these words are a blur to you or you couldn't find ideal solutions, you can comment here about your problems :)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks. I am trying it that way KINDA but I'm just struggling. I will get it though eventually :)

Comment: Some possibly helpful links for you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-possible-path-2d-matrix/ https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-count-all-paths-in-2d-matrix-with-obstructions-in-it/

Comment: Needs clarification: What's "and so on" supposed to mean? I.e. do you only have a path if there is a complete path from s[0] so s[n] where n is the size of s, or do you just want links s[i]  to s[i+1]? Also the triples are a distraction, may as well be a,b,c,..right?